# Using jQuery, how can I ajax load text into multiple .classes rather than #id's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my website I have a commenting form which tells you how long ago a comment was posted.
Below is a code to reload only the span containing the date every 10 seconds, **NOT** the entire comments div (to prevent page-lag)

```
$(function(){
     setInterval(
     function(){ 
     var id = $('.date').html();
     $('.date').load('/comdate.php?id=' + id); }
     ,10000);
});
```

my function is not working, and I don't really want to make a seperate function for every comment's date field. Please may someone point out my problem? Thanks

**EDIT**
I am using this in javascript to change the time to a readable date

```
   function prettyDate(time){
    var date = new Date((time || "").replace(/-/g,"/").replace(/[TZ]/g," ")),
        diff = (((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000),
        day_diff = Math.floor(diff / 86400);

    if ( isNaN(day_diff) || day_diff < 0 || day_diff >= 31 )
        return;

    return day_diff == 0 && (
            diff < 60 && "just now" ||
            diff < 120 && "1 minute ago" ||
            diff < 3600 && Math.floor( diff / 60 ) + " minutes ago" ||
            diff < 7200 && "1 hour ago" ||
            diff < 86400 && Math.floor( diff / 3600 ) + " hours ago") ||
        day_diff == 1 && "Yesterday" ||
        day_diff < 7 && day_diff + " days ago" ||
        day_diff < 31 && Math.ceil( day_diff / 7 ) + " weeks ago";
}

// If jQuery is included in the page, adds a jQuery plugin to handle it as well
if ( typeof jQuery != "undefined" )
    jQuery.fn.prettyDate = function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var date = prettyDate(this.title);
            if ( date )
                jQuery(this).text( date );
        });
    };
```

This returns GMT+1 though because thats where I am. how do I change this function to make the javascript timezone GMT aswell?

Comment: why you don't load the time as a timespan and calculate the time difference using javascript rather than an ajax call ?

Comment: still this function can be javascript and it will save all the calls to your server.

Comment: could you change the function into js for me?

Comment: try alert($('.date').html()); and tell me what is the value of id

Comment: it only alerts one of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion made by @ra_htial in his first comment sounds like the best one, because it doesn't poll the server needlessly with requests which could be managed on the client side with javascript. So my suggestion is to add a `data-date` attribute to your `.date` span elements, which would contain the date and time in plain format, which can be decoded in javascript and used to update the human readable date.

Here's how the html should look like with static data:

```
<span class="date" data-date="2013-09-08 12:37">1 min ago</span>
```

Or outputted from your php script:

```
<span class="date" data-date="<?php echo $date; ?>"><?php echo nicetime($date); ?></span>
```

And here's the javascript that updates the date content (I used the formatting function from this article http://www.zachleat.com/web/yet-another-pretty-date-javascript/ but there are other alternatives like John Resig's [Pretty Date](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-pretty-date/)):

```
setInterval(function()
{ 
    $('.date').each(function()
    {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html(humane_date($this.data('date')));
    });
}, 10000);
```

**EDIT**

Here's a fiddle that illustrates the functionality http://jsfiddle.net/FXERS/. You would need to change the `data-date` attribute for one of the elements in the fiddle, to your current time to see it get updated.

Comment: yours is the best @Bogdan, but how do I put a GMT date into the database?

Comment: Do you not already store the date and time of comments in your database?

Comment: i use this `$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");` but it returns in GMT -4

Comment: i guess this would work? `$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s",mktime(date("H")+4));`

Comment: or a better practice would be to set your time zone with `date_default_timezone_set`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: so `date_default_timezone_set ( 'GMT' )`

Comment: it that's the timezone you want to use, then yes

Comment: GMT is returning 1 hour ahead (GMT+1)

Answer (score 4):

For me i would change my ajax request to send the unix timespan only once and i would do all my calculations in javascript.

```
var periods = ["second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade"];
var lengths = ["60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10"];

function nicetime(user_date)
{
    if(typeof user_date == "undefined" ) {
        return "No date provided";
    }

    var now  = new Date().getTime();
    var unix_date = user_date;

    // check validity of date
    if(unix_date == "") {   
        return "Bad date";
    }

    // is it future date or past date
    if(now > unix_date) {   
        var difference = now - unix_date;
        var tense = "ago";
    } else {
        var difference = unix_date - now;
        var tense      = "from now";
    }
    difference = difference/1000; //from milliseconds to seconds;
    for(var j = 0; difference >= lengths[j] && j < lengths.length-1; j++) {
        difference /= lengths[j];
    }

    difference = Math.round(difference);

    if(difference != 1) {
        periods[j] += "s";
    }

   return difference+" "+periods[j]+" "+tense;
}


console.log(nicetime(1378632182334));
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/F6H2w/

**NOTE** 
The only thing that i changed in your function is:

```
difference = difference/1000; //from milliseconds to seconds;
```

your code was dealing with the differences variable in milliseconds which should be in seconds.

Comment: thankyou, now what php do I need for when the comment is put into the database? `$date=strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));` ?

Comment: the function accepts `unix timestamp` so depends on your approach and your database, 1- you can have a timestamp field in your database so you only need to select that field, 2- you can have a `datetime` field in your database so you need `strtotime(the_field)`. If you want the time now you can have something like `strtotime("now")`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you can use the `.load()` method on multiple elements, but you could fetch the date once into a variable and then update all the other elements:

```
$.get('/comdate.php?id=' + id, function(data) {
    $('.date').each( function() { $(this).html(data); } );
});
```

Which updates all the elements. Although pointed out above in the comments, you're not doing anything in that script you couldn't do in JS with a bit of work.

*Edited to add* Look for at the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object in JavaScript, it can get the current time and parse it -- everything else in your function is just logic which is easy to translate.

Comment: I like this idea, but will it work if all the dates are different?

Comment: Ah, no -- in that case you need to call the 'load' inside the 'each'. But that's really going to hammer the server, so I'd look at re implementing the function. I already added a link that should have all the info you need.

Comment: ok i'm going to change a few things, will this insert a Unix date into the database `$date=strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));`

Comment: That's the right format for the timestamp yes. But I'd look at the answer from ra_htial. That's a better overall approach. I misunderstood what you were trying to do in the first place.